# OSError setuptools pip failed with error code 1

Tags: python, virtualenv

Пытаюсь запустить у себя на ноуте (Debian 8.5) проект на Django, но исполнение makefile заканчивается следующим результатом

```
virtualenv oscar
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in oscar/bin/python2
Not overwriting existing python script oscar/bin/python (you must use oscar/bin/python2)
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/bin/python2 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 245, in _get_queued_page
    page = self._get_page(location, req)
  File "/home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 335, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, cache=self.cache)
  File "/home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 452, in get_page
    resp = urlopen(url)
  File "/home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 85, in __call__
    response = urllib2.urlopen(self.get_request(url))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 423, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 285, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 245, in _get_queued_page
    page = self._get_page(location, req)
  File "/home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 335, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, cache=self.cache)
  File "/home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 452, in get_page
    resp = urlopen(url)
  File "/home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 85, in __call__
    response = urllib2.urlopen(self.get_request(url))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 423, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 285, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: /usr/share/python-wheels/
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 245, in _get_queued_page
    page = self._get_page(location, req)
  File "/home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 335, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, cache=self.cache)
  File "/home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 452, in get_page
    resp = urlopen(url)
  File "/home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 85, in __call__
    response = urllib2.urlopen(self.get_request(url))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 423, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 285, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: .


Ignoring indexes: http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Downloading/unpacking distribute
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement distribute
No distributions at all found for distribute
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2378, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 830, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1032, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 975, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 917, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/miha/opt/osdj/oscar/bin/python2 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
Makefile:13: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «libs»
make: *** [libs] Ошибка 1
```

Из гугления были варианты, что версия питона старая, но у меня 2.7.9 (та до которой в решении предлагали обновляться). Так же был вариант, что версии питона в перемешку, это больше подходит. Но у меня по запросу "python" выдает нужный 2.7.9 для проекта. А про запросу python3 - не нужный третий. В коде ошибки мелькает python3, но я не понимаю откуда это и что делать с этим.  Код makefile

```
# These targets are not files
.PHONY: libs install start stop    

NAME = chem
CTX = prod
PORT = 80
DOMAIN = 127.0.0.1    

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = $(NAME).settings.$(CTX)
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE    

libs:
    aptitude -y install python-pip python-dev build-essential python-virtualenv libjpeg-dev daemon nginx uwsgi uwsgi-plugin-python git libmysqlclient-dev    

    virtualenv oscar
    oscar/bin/pip install django-oscar==1.1.1 pysolr simplejson xlrd MySQL-python 
    oscar/bin/pip uninstall -y Pillow
    oscar/bin/pip install Pillow

    rm -rf solr-4.7.2
    wget -q http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/4.7.2/solr-4.7.2.tgz -O solr-4.7.2.tgz   
    tar xzf solr-4.7.2.tgz
    mv solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1/conf solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1/conf.original
    mkdir solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1/conf
    cp -rp solr.conf/* solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1/conf

# git clone https://Ilya_tt@bitbucket.org/Ilya_tt/chem.git
# change chem/settings/prod.py MYSQL

install:    
    python confgen.py $(NAME) $(CTX) $(DOMAIN) $(PORT)

    rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/$(NAME)_nginx.conf
    rm -rf /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/$(NAME)_uwsgi.ini

    ln -s $(shell pwd)/$(NAME)_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
    ln -s $(shell pwd)/$(NAME)_uwsgi.ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/

    chmod 744 solr.run  
    chown -R www-data pid
    chgrp -R www-data pid   
    chown -R www-data logs
    chgrp -R www-data logs
    chown -R www-data $(NAME)/public
    chgrp -R www-data $(NAME)/public

    oscar/bin/python $(NAME)/manage.py migrate
    oscar/bin/python $(NAME)/manage.py loaddata init
    oscar/bin/python $(NAME)/manage.py loaddata flatpage
    oscar/bin/python $(NAME)/manage.py loaddata offer
    oscar/bin/python $(NAME)/manage.py collectstatic --noinput

    chown -R www-data $(NAME)/public
    chgrp -R www-data $(NAME)/public

static:
    oscar/bin/python $(NAME)/manage.py collectstatic --noinput

start:  
    ./solr.run start
    service uwsgi restart

stop:       
    service uwsgi stop
    ./solr.run stop
```

Вопрос, что сделать чтобы избежать этой ошибки?

dpkg -l | grep wheel 
ii  python-setuptools-whl                 5.5.1-1                              all          Python Distutils Enhancements (wheel package)
ii  python-six-whl                        1.8.0-1                              all          Python 2 and 3 compatibility library (universal wheel)
ii  python-wheel                          0.24.0-1                             all          built-package format for Python

Comment: > python-wheels Вероятнее всего тут ошибка. Удалите пакет python-wheels или python2-wheels и всё должно заработать. Сам с таким боролся, правда на 3 питоне

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Я пытался apt-get remove и pip uninstall с различными вариантами python-wheels или python2-wheels, wheel пишет что такого пакета не найдено

Comment: dpkg -l | grep wheel посмотрите

Comment: нашлось 3 пакета, все 3 удалил. Проверил - больше нет. Запустил makefile опять та же ошибка. После появилось опять 2 пакета python-setuptools-whl И python-six-whl

Comment: Почему-то мне всё же кажется, что проблема из-за этого. Попробуйте пакеты по одному из pip install установить в виртуальное окружение, может какой-то из них сбоит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось ошибка выполнялась командой

```
virtualenv oscar
```

В этой папке уже была папка "oscar", удалил - всё прошло.